# curl giving 500 error code

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to use the curl method and keep getting a 500 error. Although when I run a test php script that only has curl it will work smoothly.

This is the code that works:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $goto_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id_of=".$id."&sqlreq=".$sqlreq);
    // execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

And on my other file I try this:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $goto_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id_of=".$id."&sqlreq=".$sqreq);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

The difference between the files is that there is data being processed in the second file. I thought maybe I needed to close my sql connection but then that didn't work. The code seems to work. I'm not sure what's wrong. Also note when I comment out curl_exec($ch) then no error occurs.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: So then the error lays within the `data being processed` and not within cURL, please post that code aswell.

Comment: I thought that would be the error but 500 error doesn't happen when I comment out the curl_exec line

Answer (score 0):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id_of=".$id."&sqlreq=".$sqreq);
```

should be

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "id_of=".$id."&sqlreq=".$sqlreq);
```

you have typoo there. *sqreq* -> *sqlreq*.